# How do I check the start time of windows/explorer from batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, time, cmd

I'm attempting to get the time of when windows booted, while using batch, then change the current system time to when windows booted, execute a command, then change back to the current time.  I know how to store the current time, then using that information to change back to its original time after the commands are ran, I'm just not sure how to get the time of when Windows started, or explorer since explorer starts with windows.

Example:

```
'Storing the current system time so we can change back to it at the end.
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('time /t') DO SET CurrentTime=%%i

'Change System time to when Windows booted [Not sure how to do this part]
time %WindowsBootTime%

'Run Commands

'Now change back to it's original time.
time %CurrentTime%
```

Comment: You can retieve the information with `wmic os get LastBootUpTime`. Retrieve it with `for /f` and use substring operations to split the timestamp (see `set /?`) to adapt the time to your locale time format.

Comment: You can also get the system boot time from **SYSTEMINFO**. `systeminfo |find "System Boot"`.  Again you can use a `FOR /F` to get the output into a variable.

Comment: `systeminfo` is slooow. And it's output is language specific. On my system, I would have to `find "Systemstartzeit"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I'm attempting to get the time of when windows booted

Use the following batch file (**GetBootTime.cmd**)

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%a in ('wmic os get lastbootuptime ^| find "."') do (
  set _datetime=%%a
  )
set _boottime=%_datetime:~0,4%-%_datetime:~4,2%-%_datetime:~6,2% %_datetime:~8,2%:%_datetime:~10,2%
echo %_boottime%
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
> GetBootTime.cmd
2016-12-20 23:49
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.